# Workflow for Using Django South with Multiple Code Branches

Tags: django, branch, django-south

I'm curious as to how other Django devs manage their database migrations with South when developing with multiple code branches. Let me give a sample scenario.

Say for example you start you development with your main trunk. You create Branch A from the trunk. At this point, the last migration version for `app_1` is 0010.

Then you create a migration for `app_1` in the trunk that creates a migration file `0011_add_name_column`. Meanwhile, in branch A, another developer creates a different migration file for the same `app_1` in branch A: `0011_increase_value_column_size`.

Branch A eventually gets merged back to trunk. When this happens, say last migration version in `app_1` in Branch A is `0020` and in the trunk the last version is `0018`, and they're all different migrations. As you can see, the state of the migration files are messed up since version `0011`, when the branch was forked from trunk.. and they're all in conflicts upon merging.

According to [South's tutorial](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part5.html), the only way to handle this case is to manually resolve all the conflicts. However, this is not really a desired solution if the amount of conflicts are significant. How do you typically handle this situation, or even to avoid it in the first place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, the answer to this is not very straightforward.

**TL;DR update**: 
In most cases, if we are talking a Trunk <-> Branch workflow I would probably

1. "Compress" new migrations from Branch A into a single migration (or least possible)
2. Merge all trunk changes/migrations to Branch A.
3. Rename Branch A migrations to 0019 and so on.
4. Now merge to trunk.

**More detail**

First of all, it doesn't matter if you have multiple migrations with same prefix (i.e. `0011`) from merging different branches, **as long as** they don't modify the same models. Then you can simply run migrate with the `--merge` option to apply out of order migrations.

But if you have two different "migration paths" from 0011 -> 0018 and 0011 -> 0020 for the same app, even if they don't touch the same models, that's not very pretty. I think it's likely that either:

1. Those branches have been separated for a **very long** time and there's a large disparity in the 2 schemas. There are 2 possible situations here:

   - They don't touch the same models (i.e they don't "intersect"): You can just apply them out of order with `--merge`, **however** it's very likely the affected models should better belong to 2 separate apps instead.
   - They **do** touch the same models (which I assume it's probably your case): I have to concur with `@chrisdpratt` here, that it's best to avoid this situation altogether by coordinating/splitting up work better. **But** even in this case, especially if you have only schema migrations, and you don't do some obviously conflicting schema migrations in the two branches (a stupid example would be adding a field with the same name to same model in 2 different migrations), it's pretty likely that you can just apply the migrations (or at least most of them) out of order with `--merge` without problems. In many cases the order of the schema migrations won't matter even if they affect the same model, you do need to check this manually however. And when it's an issue, you'll just have to change their numbering, there's no automatic way around it.
2. You generate a new schema migration for every little schema change: There's nothing wrong with this during development, but once the feature is complete (ready for merging) the migrations should be "compressed" into a single migration (or at least less migrations if there are a lot of changes with some logical grouping, or if you also have data migrations). On dev environment which is already on latest migration, it's simple to just do

   - ./manage.py migrate myapp 0010 --fake
   - delete migrations 0011-0018
   - ./manage.py schemamigration myapp schema_changes_for_new_feature_x --auto
   - ./manage.py migrate myapp 0011 --fake --delete-ghost-migrations

Another thing is, that after merging between two branches with different migrations, you'll often need to create a `mergefix` schema migration (with empty forwards/backwards) methods, to record the combined state in the "frozen" models (otherwise `South` will think there are outstanding schema changes)

Answer (score 10):

My answer has been not committing migrations when possible. Migrations can always be regenerated if lost, so assuming no one but me needs to run my branch, just don't commit your migrations until the very end.

Short of that, the best method I've found is to simply treat them as merge conflicts. When you merge back into trunk, check your migration folder(s), and independently resolve each numbering conflict by renaming your migrations to higher numbers.

Granted, neither method is ideal, but there's not a whole lot of options on this front. [South's own advice on the matter](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part5.html) is to not develop in a vacuum. Merge often and communicate with the other developers you're working with.

> South is no substitute for team coordination [...] Make sure your team know who is working on what, so they don’t write migrations that affect the same parts of the DB at the same time.

While that advice may sound frustrating on the surface, in reality, the principle is right. More than just concerning migrations, it's never really a good idea to have multiple developers working on the same bit of the system at the same time. Assign similar tasks to the same developer who is already working on that piece of the system, and you won't have any problems.

Comment: It's not always possible to generate them, I have had to write manual migrations before and in that circumstance they need to be committed to source control

Comment: I've done a *lot* of migrations with South. I've never ever needed to write a *schema migration* manually. Now, data migrations are a different story and obviously you would not want to delete any custom data migrations. However, if you're doing a data migration *inside* a schema migration, you're doing it wrong. Otherwise, I'd look *very* closely at just why you needed a custom schema migration, because I've never encountered a single scenario in over two years of using Django with South migrations where that was actually needed.

Comment: I would not say it's a common occurrence, but in many years of Django and South usage i've had to do it a couple of times. Every time it was either due to an error on the part of someone on the team, a conflict resulting from two migrations in different branches or a problem with using different DB technologies in dev and production. It's certainly always a bad thing when it happens, but it has happened and I am glad those migrations were in source control when it did.