# How to fix a Database Error and ghost migration error in Django?

Tags: python, django, model, django-south

I am getting an DatabaseError saying no column named playlist exists and I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.  I'm using South. I deleted the old files in the my migrations folder and ran:

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial
python manage.py migrate reserve
```

I get this error when I do that:

```
south.exceptions.GhostMigrations: 

 ! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:
    <reserve: 0002_initial>
 ! I'm not trusting myself; either fix this yourself by fiddling
 ! with the south_migrationhistory table, or pass --delete-ghost-migrations
 ! to South to have it delete ALL of these records (this may not be good).
```

I'm not sure how to get rid of this error, since in my migrations folder I only have init.py(c) and 0001_initial.py(c); I don't have 0002 migration file anymore.

When I try runserver and click "add playlist" in the admin, this is when I get the DatabaseError.  If it helps, my models.py is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)         

class Playlist(models.Model):
    playlist = models.CharField('Playlist', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.playlist

class Video(models.Model):
    video_url = models.URLField('Link to video', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video_url

class UserPlaylist(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.playlist

class Videoplaylist(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(UserPlaylist)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.playlist
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Django South GhostMigrations exception and how do you debug it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875459/what-is-a-django-south-ghostmigrations-exception-and-how-do-you-debug-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South stores migration information in the database too, in a table called "migrations". [ I think thats the table name; writing this from memory ].

You need to clear that table out.

**Note**

- Once you clear that table out, you have to start the migrations again from scratch; right from the initial migration.
- It would be a good idea to make a copy of your database as-is before you do this. I assume that your code is already version controlled.

Comment: Would you recommend manage.py reset south or manage.py sqlclear app_name?

Answer (score 12):

Just run

```
python manage.py migrate reserve --delete-ghost-migrations
```

This should remove non existing migration from the database table `south_migrationhistory`.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should work out what happened to get the db and filesystem out of sync.

Then, if appropriate, you can do

```
python manage.py migrate reserve --ignore-ghost-migrations
```

or

```
python manage.py migrate reserve --delete-ghost-migrations
```

as Aidas said, whichever seems more appropriate.  The `ignore` option is probably less risky, although something has already gone astray for you to get to this state.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error happens because, you created a migration file and did the migration then, that migration file was deleted from your file system(disk)

So you have changes in your database caused by a migration that no longer exists. 
Depending on whether you deleted the migration file file by choice, what you can do; is go ahead and also delete the changes from the database.

Start the python shell;
$ `python manage.py shell`

```
>>from south.models import MigrationHistory
>>MigrationHistory.objects.filter(migration='0002_initial').delete()
```

That will have deleted the 0002 migration from the db.
You can now go ahead and create/recreate the migration you want.

Goodluck,
Komu.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command where manage.py file is present in your directory

> ./manage.py migrate appname --delete-ghost-migrations