# How to make migrations for app in django 1.5

Tags: django, migration

Since the makemigrations command is not available in Django 1.5, I am not sure how to use migrations to sync all django apps. The migrate command does not solve the issue and I instead get a GhostMigrations error and "! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you know you're using a 3rd party library to handle migrations in Django 1.5? The library, South, was adapted and adopted as core Django from version 1.7+. But migrations with pre-1.7 Django and South use slightly different syntax from the later core migrations. For example, you use the command `manage.py schemamigration` along with flags like `--initial` and `--auto`, rather than `makemigrations`. [Official docs](https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) here. See [this guide](https://test-driven-django-development.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0/08-south.html) for a walkthrough. And see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875459/what-is-a-django-south-ghostmigrations-exception-and-how-do-you-debug-it) about GhostMigrations.

Better still, upgrade your Django project to a minimum of 1.7 and then you can use the simpler `makemigrations` command.

Comment: Very informative for those unfortunate enough to be trapped in the past.